# How do I calculate number of working days from previous row in the resultset?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

Can someone please help me with this confusing situation?  I have a table generated in SQL Server 2008.

```
Number  Date
------  ---------
22619   30/06/11
22617   01/07/11
22556   03/07/11
22556   03/07/11
22560   04/07/11
22560   05/07/11
22560   08/07/11
22561   07/07/11
22561   17/07/11
22564   09/07/11
22564   20/07/11
```

I want to generate days from the previous role for each number which are the same below.

And I want to return the following:

```
Number  Date        Days
------  ----------  ----
22619   30/06/11       0
22617   01/07/11       0
22556   03/07/11       0
22556   03/07/11       0
22560   04/07/11       0
22560   05/07/11       1
22560   08/07/11       3
22561   07/07/11       0
22561   17/07/11      10
22564   09/07/11       0
22564   20/07/11      11
```

Any assistance is highly appreciated

Comment: Do you have a calendar table that indicates your company's "working days"? Otherwise you're going to have to write all kinds of exceptions for cases when the previous day was Christmas, company holidays, etc. Also the results you want seem to completely ignore that there are non-working days between your dates. I'm confused.

Comment: to add to @AaronBertrand 's comment, you will at least need a table with holidays and some sort of function to calculate business days.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this:

```
with data as (
    select number = 22619, date = convert(datetime, '20110630') union all
    select 22617, convert(datetime, '20110701') union all
    select 22556, convert(datetime, '20110703') union all
    select 22556, convert(datetime, '20110703') union all
    select 22560, convert(datetime, '20110704') union all
    select 22560, convert(datetime, '20110705') union all
    select 22560, convert(datetime, '20110708') union all
    select 22561, convert(datetime, '20110707') union all
    select 22561, convert(datetime, '20110717') union all
    select 22564, convert(datetime, '20110709') union all
    select 22564, convert(datetime, '20110720')
)
select next.number, next.date, days = isnull(DATEDIFF(dd, prev.date, next.date),0)
from (
    select *, sequence_no = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY number ORDER BY date ASC)
    from data
) next
left join (
    select *, sequence_no = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY number ORDER BY date ASC)
    from data
) prev
on prev.number = next.number
and prev.sequence_no + 1 = next.sequence_no
```

Comment: While this is what the "results" above seem to indicate the OP wants as output, the inclusion of "working days" seems to imply that there needs to be some consideration here for days that are Saturday/Sunday (never mind any holidays or other "non-working days" may be involved).

Comment: I don't think this answers the question.  You are not taking into consideration that they want working days, not just the difference between days.

Comment: And where is he writing anything about working days? I can't see?

Comment: Oww, the question title.. So you're both right, my query is not taking into consideration notion of the working day. Still, it may be a starting point for a complete solution.